# Magento checkout cart fieldset - how to remove annoying colon showing

Tags: php, checkout, cart

In my checkout cart of magento using a custom template I get this annoying colon showing above the cart items:

It just showing a colon, its not affecting anything, but it looks like "this shop is not working", it gives some wrong signals to the user, I think...

The frontend source shows:

```
<fieldset>      
   :

<table id="shopping-cart-table" class="data-table cart-table">
```

...and there we have it...!!! - the colon showing just after the fieldset.

cart.phtml i have testet and come up with the conclusion that it must be related to the getItemHtml($_item) ?>

First, what is it supposed to shown ? 
Second, how do I remove it or at least hide it ?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like some translation issue or custom module/template typo!

You should enable Template path hints in System / Configuration / Developer (be sure to select the correct site and set the correct IP's for restriction, better would be to do this on a local development environment)

See which files are affected if you refresh the page, open these and check what's within.

I always empty a whole file to start with and see if the colon is still there, if it isn't you know you are on the right track.

If it is a translation, you should check those files too. (see table core_translate)

Comment: How can I see which files are affected ?

Comment: See my second paragraph. Enable path hints!